# How to download polygons drawn in leaflet.draw as GeoJson file, from R (Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I created an application in R-shiny, using the leaflet.extra package, I put a map in which my users can draw polygons, my goal is to be able to download the polygons that my users drew as a GeoJson or Shapefil (.shp) .
My application looks like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(


textOutput("text"),leafletOutput("mymap")  )
```

and server:

```
poly<-reactiveValues(poligonos=list()) #save reactiveValues



output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({

     leaflet("mymap") %>%
      addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, #map type or map theme. -default($Stame.TonerLite)
                       options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE) 

      )%>% addDrawToolbar(
        targetGroup='draw',
        editOptions = editToolbarOptions(selectedPathOptions = selectedPathOptions()))  %>%
      addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c('draw'), options =
                         layersControlOptions(collapsed=FALSE)) %>%
      addStyleEditor()




  })  

 polygons<- eventReactive(input$mymap_draw_all_features, {

   features<-input$mymap_draw_all_features
   poly$poligonos<-c(poly$poligonos,features)

   return(poly$poligonos)

  })
```

The eventReactive function called "polygons" is responsible for recording the polygons (coordinates) that are drawn, but i din't know how to save them or convert into a GeoJson or shapefile format.

Comment: try the [mapedit package](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapedit). It does all the work for you. See http://r-spatial.org/r/2017/06/09/mapedit_0-2-0.html on how to use it within a shiny app.

Answer (score 9):

What you can do is take the coordinates of the polygons you made with the DrawToolbar and use them to create polygons in a `reactiveValues` SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.  You can export that SPDF as a shapefile (with the example below you have to publish to the server to make the download option work.  It will not work from R Studio).

```
ui <- fluidPage(

textOutput("text"),leafletOutput("mymap"),
downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download Shp'))
```

--

```
server<- function(input, output, session) {

output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({

  leaflet("mymap") %>%
   addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, #map type or map theme. -default($Stame.TonerLite)
                 options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>% 
   addDrawToolbar(targetGroup = "drawnPoly", 
                    rectangleOptions = F, 
                    polylineOptions = F, 
                    markerOptions = F, 
                    editOptions = editToolbarOptions(selectedPathOptions = selectedPathOptions()), 
                    circleOptions=F,
                    polygonOptions=drawPolygonOptions(showArea=TRUE, repeatMode=F  , shapeOptions=drawShapeOptions( fillColor="red",clickable = TRUE))) %>%

    addStyleEditor()

  })



latlongs<-reactiveValues()   #temporary to hold coords
latlongs$df2 <- data.frame(Longitude = numeric(0), Latitude = numeric(0))

#########
#empty reactive spdf
value<-reactiveValues()
SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpatialPolygons(list()), data=data.frame (notes=character(0), stringsAsFactors = F))->value$drawnPoly

#fix the polygon to start another

observeEvent(input$mymap_draw_new_feature, {

  coor<-unlist(input$mymap_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates)

  Longitude<-coor[seq(1,length(coor), 2)] 

  Latitude<-coor[seq(2,length(coor), 2)]

  isolate(latlongs$df2<-rbind(latlongs$df2, cbind(Longitude, Latitude)))

  poly<-Polygon(cbind(latlongs$df2$Longitude, latlongs$df2$Latitude))
  polys<-Polygons(list(poly),    ID=input$mymap_draw_new_feature$properties$`_leaflet_id`)
  spPolys<-SpatialPolygons(list(polys))


  #
  value$drawnPoly<-rbind(value$drawnPoly,SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(spPolys, 
                                                                 data=data.frame(notes=NA, row.names=
                                                                                row.names(spPolys))))

###plot upon ending draw
 observeEvent(input$mymap_draw_stop, {

 #replot it - take off the DrawToolbar to clear the features and add it back and use the values from the SPDF to plot the polygons
  leafletProxy('mymap') %>%  removeDrawToolbar(clearFeatures=TRUE) %>% removeShape('temp') %>% clearGroup('drawnPoly') %>% addPolygons(data=value$drawnPoly, popup="poly",   group='drawnPoly', color="blue", layerId=row.names(value$drawnPoly)) %>% 

  addDrawToolbar(targetGroup = "drawnPoly", 
                 rectangleOptions = F, 
                 polylineOptions = F, 
                 markerOptions = F, 
                 editOptions = editToolbarOptions(selectedPathOptions = selectedPathOptions()), 
                 circleOptions=F,
                 polygonOptions=drawPolygonOptions(showArea=TRUE, repeatMode=F  , shapeOptions=drawShapeOptions( fillColor="red",clickable = TRUE)))

})

 latlongs$df2 <- data.frame(Longitude = numeric(0), Latitude = numeric(0))   #clear df

 })

########################
### edit polygons / delete polygons

observeEvent(input$mymap_draw_edited_features, {

 f <- input$mymap_draw_edited_features

  coordy<-lapply(f$features, function(x){unlist(x$geometry$coordinates)})

  Longitudes<-lapply(coordy, function(coor) {coor[seq(1,length(coor), 2)] })

  Latitudes<-lapply(coordy, function(coor) { coor[seq(2,length(coor), 2)] })

  polys<-list()
  for (i in 1:length(Longitudes)){polys[[i]]<- Polygons(
list(Polygon(cbind(Longitudes[[i]], Latitudes[[i]]))), ID=f$features[[i]]$properties$layerId
  )}

  spPolys<-SpatialPolygons(polys)


  SPDF<-SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(spPolys, 
                             data=data.frame(notes=value$drawnPoly$notes[row.names(value$drawnPoly) %in% row.names(spPolys)], row.names=row.names(spPolys)))

  value$drawnPoly<-value$drawnPoly[!row.names(value$drawnPoly) %in% row.names(SPDF),]
value$drawnPoly<-rbind(value$drawnPoly, SPDF)

  })

 observeEvent(input$mymap_draw_deleted_features, { 

   f <- input$mymap_draw_deleted_features

   ids<-lapply(f$features, function(x){unlist(x$properties$layerId)})


      value$drawnPoly<-value$drawnPoly[!row.names(value$drawnPoly) %in% ids ,]

 }) 



  #write the polys to .shp
  output$downloadData<-downloadHandler(

  filename = 'shpExport.zip',
 content = function(file) {
  if (length(Sys.glob("shpExport.*"))>0){
  file.remove(Sys.glob("shpExport.*"))
}

  proj4string(value$drawnPoly)<-"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
   writeOGR(value$drawnPoly, dsn="shpExport.shp", layer="shpExport", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
  zip(zipfile='shpExport.zip', files=Sys.glob("shpExport.*"))
  file.copy("shpExport.zip", file)
   if (length(Sys.glob("shpExport.*"))>0){
    file.remove(Sys.glob("shpExport.*"))
   }
 }
 )

}
```

--

```
 shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Need to add the following for this code to work: `require(sp)
require(leaflet)
require(leaflet.extras)`

Comment: plus  require(rgdal)

Comment: As of January 2022, the R package `leaflet.extras` is abandoned (see [their GitHub repo](https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras) and considered a potential security risk.