# Handling polygon edits in shiny app using leafpm

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-sf

I am working on a shiny app that lets users interactively draw polygons on a leaflet map using the "leafpm" package, calculate forest biometrics, report them, and make those polygons available to download.  I think I have may app almost complete, but I am struggling to handle edits to the polygon.

I adapted my code from this Stack Overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979900/how-to-download-polygons-drawn-in-leaflet-draw-as-geojson-file-from-r-shiny), which uses the now deprecated "sp" package to handle the polygons.  I instead use the "sf" package.  In my `observeEvent()` function, I attempt to handle polygon edits, by dropping the feature with the same unique identifier supplied by the reactive shiny object `input$MAP_draw_edited_features$properties$layerId` from `polys$out` (which is the `reactiveValues()` object that I define to store all of the drawn polygons), and then using `rbind()` to add the edited feature back in.  I store the unique identifier from the reactive shiny object as the row names in `polys$out`.  I store the edited feature as an "sf" object called `sfp`, which also has its unique identifier stored as its row name.  The idea is that I can query based on non-matching row names to remove the old version of the edited feature from `polys$out`, and then use `rbind()` to add `sfp` back into `polys$out` with the same unique identifier, so that users see only the changes in geometry.  Strangely, when I test this, my edits seem to result in an the edited feature sequentially overwriting the geometries of unedited features.

At first, I ran a number of `isolate(print(row.names(polys$out)))` statements to see if somehow my method of querying on row name was flawed.  It turned out that using `rbind()` overwrote the row names, so I explicitly redefined the row names following my schema described above.  After doing that, I was able to ensure that the correct row name for the edited feature was being dropped, and then added back in.  However, the geometries are still getting overwritten.  Do I need to somehow break the `observeEvent()` after each edits to prevent this from happening?  Am I somehow overwriting the wrong row names to the wrong feature?

Below is my full reproducible example.  Please draw at least 3 - 4 polygons, check the table for the values, then make at least two edits to the polygons,  and then check the table again to reproduce the behavior I describe.

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(leafpm)
library(terra)
library(shinydashboard)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(56)

BAA<-rast(xmin= -124.0, xmax=-121.0, ymin=44.0, ymax=46.0, nrows=500, ncols=500, crs="epsg:4326")
values(BAA)<-rnorm(250000, 150, 40)

rastpath<-tempdir()

if(!dir.exists(rastpath)){
  dir.create(tempdir)
}

writeRaster(BAA, paste(normalizePath(rastpath,"/"), "Basal Area per Acre.tif", sep="/"), overwrite=TRUE)

SPP<-BAA
species<-c("THPL", "ALRU2", "ACMA3", 
           "PSME", "TSHE", "PISI", "ABPR")

values(SPP)<-sample(species, 250000, replace=TRUE)
writeRaster(SPP, paste(normalizePath(rastpath,"/"), "Species Composition.tif", sep="/"), overwrite=TRUE)

ui<-dashboardPage(
  title = "EFI Interactive Mapper",# Start Dashboard Page
  header = dashboardHeader(
    tags$li(class = "dropdown",
            tags$style(".main-header {max-height: 100px}"),
            tags$style(".main-header .logo {height: 100px} .primary-title height {100px}"),
            tags$style(".sidebar-toggle {height: 20px; padding-top: 150px !important;}"),
            tags$style(".navbar {min-height:20px !important}")
    ),
    titleWidth='100%',
    title = span(
      tags$img(src="Rlogo.png", width = '5%', align='right'), 
      column(12, class="title-box", 
             tags$h1(class="primary-title", style='margin-top:5px;', 'EFI Interactive Mapper')
      ))),#End Header
  dashboardSidebar(tags$style(".left-side, .main-sidebar {padding-top: 150px} "),selectInput(inputId = "BIO", "Select a Biometric", 
                                                                                             choices = c("Basal Area per Acre", "Species Composition", "All Biometrics"),
                                                                                             selected = "Basal Area Per Acre"), tags$style(".skin-blue .sidebar a { color: #444; }"),
                   downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download Polygon')
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      tabBox(
        tabPanel('Map', div(style='height:63.0vh', leafletOutput(outputId = "MAP", height="100%"))),
        tabPanel('Table', div(style='overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto; max-height:63.0vh', uiOutput("TABLE"))),
        width=12, selected='Table'
      )
    )
  )
)

server<-function(input, output, session){
  
  Bios<-c( "Species Composition", "Basal Area per Acre")
  
  
  tifnames<-c('Species Composition.tif', "Basal Area Per Acre.tif")
  

  rastdf<-data.frame(Bio=Bios[order(Bios)],  paths=paste(normalizePath(rastpath, "/"), tifnames, sep="/"))
  tmp<-lapply(rastdf$paths, rast)
  bio_ras<-c(tmp)
  names(bio_ras)<-rastdf$Bio
  

  
  output$MAP<-renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng=-123.5, lat=45.5, zoom = 10) %>% 
  
      addWMSTiles(
        "https://gis.odf.oregon.gov/ags3/rest/services/Basemaps/ProtectionMap/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}",
        layers = "0",
        options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE),
        attribution = "") %>% 
      
      addPmToolbar(
        toolbarOptions = pmToolbarOptions(drawPolygon = T,
                                          drawCircle = F,
                                          drawPolyline = F,
                                          drawRectangle = F,
                                          editMode = T,
                                          cutPolygon = T,
                                          removalMode = F,
                                          position="topleft"))
  })
  
  proxy <- leafletProxy("MAP", session)
  
  poly<-reactiveValues()
  coords<-reactiveValues()

  
  bio_extract<-reactive({
    if(!is.null(poly$out)){
      
      if(input$BIO=="All Biometrics"){
        bio_use<-bio_ras
      } else{ 
        bio_use<-bio_ras[names(bio_ras)==input$BIO][[1]]
      }  

      fnx<-function(x){
        themean<-mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
        thesd<-sqrt(var(x, na.rm=TRUE))
        out<-list(mean=round(themean,2), sd=round(thesd,2))
        return(out)
      }
      shapevect<-poly$out
      if(input$BIO=="Species Composition"){
        fqt<-freq(bio_use, zones=vect(shapevect)) %>% mutate(pct_comp = 100*count/sum(count))
        
        all_spp<-as.data.frame(expand.grid(levels(bio_use)[[1]][,2], unique(fqt$zone)))
        colnames(all_spp)[1:2]<-c("Species", "ID")
        use_cols<-c("value", "zone", "pct_comp")
        all_spp<-merge(all_spp, fqt[,use_cols], by.x=c("Species", "ID"), by.y=c("value", "zone"), all.x=TRUE, all.y=FALSE)
        all_spp$pct_comp[is.na(all_spp$pct_comp)]<-0
        spp_out<-tidyr::pivot_wider(all_spp, id_cols=ID, names_from = Species, values_from = pct_comp) %>% as.data.frame()
        e<-cbind(shapevect, as.data.frame(spp_out))
        #cbind(shapevect, spp_out)
        
      }else{
        if(input$BIO=="All Biometrics"){
          ext_ras<-bio_use[names(bio_use)!= "Species Composition"]
          
          e <- lapply(ext_ras, extract, shapevect, fnx, bind = FALSE, raw=FALSE)
          
          spp_ras<-bio_use[names(bio_use)== "Species Composition"][[1]]
          fqt<-freq(spp_ras, zones=vect(shapevect)) %>% mutate(pct_comp = 100*count/sum(count))
          
          all_spp<-as.data.frame(expand.grid(levels(spp_ras)[[1]][,2], unique(fqt$zone)))
          colnames(all_spp)[1:2]<-c("Species", "ID")
          use_cols<-c("value", "zone", "pct_comp")
          all_spp<-merge(all_spp, fqt[,use_cols], by.x=c("Species", "ID"), by.y=c("value", "zone"), all.x=TRUE, all.y=FALSE)
          all_spp$pct_comp[is.na(all_spp$pct_comp)]<-0
          spp_out<-tidyr::pivot_wider(all_spp, id_cols=ID, names_from = Species, values_from = pct_comp) %>% as.data.frame()
          e[[length(e)+1]]<-spp_out
          names(e)[length(e)]<-"Species Composition"
          e<-lapply(e, function(X, Y){cbind(Y, as.data.frame(X))}, shapevect) 
        }else{
          e <- terra::extract(bio_use, shapevect, fnx, bind = FALSE)
          
          e<-cbind(shapevect, as.data.frame(e))
          #   st_as_sf(cbind(shapevect, e[, -1, drop = FALSE]))
        }
      } 
      
      return(e)
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$MAP_draw_new_feature, {
    req(input$BIO)
    coords$dtf<-data.frame(do.call( rbind, do.call(cbind,input$MAP_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates)))
    colnames(coords$dtf)<-c("long", "lat")
    sfp <- coords$dtf %>%
      st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
      summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
      st_cast("POLYGON") %>% st_transform(crs=6557) %>% st_as_sf()
    
    row.names(sfp)<-input$MAP_draw_new_feature$properties$layerId
    if(is.null(poly$out)){
      poly$out<-sfp
      isolate(print(row.names(poly$out)))
    }else{
      rn<-row.names(poly$out)
      poly$out<-rbind(poly$out, sfp)
      row.names(poly$out)[-nrow(poly$out)]<-rn
      row.names(poly$out)[nrow(poly$out)]<-row.names(sfp)
      isolate(print(row.names(poly$out)))
    }
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$MAP_draw_edited_features, {
    
    dtf<-data.frame(do.call(rbind, do.call(cbind, input$MAP_draw_edited_features$geometry$coordinates)))
    colnames(dtf)<-c("long", "lat")
    
    sfp <- coords$dtf %>%
      st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
      summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
      st_cast("POLYGON") %>% st_transform(crs=6557) %>% st_as_sf()
    
    row.names(sfp)<-input$MAP_draw_edited_features$properties$layerId
    rn<-row.names(poly$out)
    isolate(poly$out)
    poly$out<-poly$out[!row.names(poly$out) %in% row.names(sfp),]
    
    row.names(poly$out)<-rn[!rn %in% rownames(sfp)]
    isolate(poly$out)
    poly$out<-rbind(poly$out, sfp)
    row.names(poly$out)[1:(nrow(poly$out)-1)]<-rn[!rn %in% rownames(sfp)]
    row.names(poly$out)[nrow(poly$out)]<-row.names(sfp)
    
    isolate(poly$out)
    
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$drawnPoly_deleted_features, { 
    
    f <- input$drawnPoly_deleted_features
    ids<-lapply(f$features, function(x){unlist(x$properties$layerId)})
    polys$out<-polys$out[!row.names(polys$out) %in% ids ,]
    
  }) 
  
  output$TABLE<-renderUI({
    req(input$BIO)
    if(!is.null(poly$out)){
      data.out<-bio_extract() 
      
      if(input$BIO=="All Biometrics"){
        
        for(i in 1:length(data.out)){
          if(i < length(data.out)){
            data.out[[i]]<-as.data.frame(data.out[[i]] %>% st_drop_geometry())
            
            colnames(data.out[[i]])<-c("Area of Interest","Estimate Mean", "Estimate Standard Deviation",
                                       "Lower Bound <br> 95% Prediction Interval <br> Mean", "Lower Bound <br> 95% Prediction Interval <br> Standard Deviation",
                                       "Upper Bound <br> 95% Prediction Interval <br> Mean", "Upper Bound <br> 95% Prediction Interval <br> Standard Deviation")
          }else{
            data.out[[i]]<-data.out[[i]] %>% st_drop_geometry() %>% mutate(across(.cols=everything(), ~paste(round(.x, 1), "%"))) %>% as.data.frame()
            
            colnames(data.out[[i]])[1]<-"Area of Interest"
          }
          
        }
        
        kbl_out<-lapply(data.out, function(X){
          kbl(X, format="html", align="c", escape=FALSE, col.names=colnames(X)) %>% 
            column_spec(column=c(1:ncol(X)), width_min="3.5cm") %>% 
            kable_styling()
        })
        
        table_formatter<-function(tname, tkbl){
          paste0("<center><b><u><font size = '+2'>", tname, "</font></u></b></center>",
                 "<br><center>", tkbl, "</center><br>")}
        
        HTML(table_formatter(names(data.out), kbl_out))
        
      }else{
        data.out<-data.out %>% st_drop_geometry()
        table_formatter<-function(tname, tkbl){
          paste0("<center><b><u><font size = '+2'>", tname, "</font></u></b></center>",
                 "<br><center>", tkbl, "</center><br>")}
        
        if(input$BIO!="Species Composition"){
          use_names<-c("Area of Interest","Estimate Mean", "Estimate Standard Deviation",
                       "Lower Bound <br> 95% Prediction Interval <br> Mean", "Lower Bound <br> 95% Prediction Interval <br> Standard Deviation",
                       "Upper Bound <br> 95% Prediction Interval <br> Mean", "Upper Bound <br> 95% Prediction Interval <br> Standard Deviation")
        }else{
          
          use_names<-colnames(data.out)
          data.out<-data.out %>% mutate(across(.cols=everything(), ~paste(round(.x, 1), "%")))
        }
        kbl_out<-kbl(data.out, format="html", escape = FALSE, col.names=use_names, align="c") %>% 
          column_spec(column=c(1:ncol(data.out)), width_min = "3.5cm") %>% 
          kable_styling()
        HTML(table_formatter(input$BIO, kbl_out))
      }
    }  
  })
  
  output$downloadData<-downloadHandler(
    
    filename <- function(){
      fname<-input$BIO
      paste(fname, "Polygon.gpkg", sep="_")}, 
    
    content = function(file) {
      #   req(polys$out)
      if (length(Sys.glob(paste(input$BIO, "*", sep=".")))>0){
        file.remove(Sys.glob(paste(input$BIO, "*", sep=".")))
      }
      
      owd<-setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      polys_out<-bio.extract()
      if(input$BIO=="All Biometrics"){
        polys_out2<-rapply(polys_out, function(X){merge(X, X, by=names(X)[1])}, how="replace")
      }else{
        polys_out2<-polys_out
      }
      st_write(polys_out2, "polyExport.gpkg", "GPKG", append=FALSE)  
      file.rename("polyExport.gpkg", file)  
      
      if (length(Sys.glob("polyExport.*"))>0){
        file.remove(Sys.glob("polyExport.*"))
      }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this was just a typo on my part. In the call to `observeEvent()`, I had this chunk of code that creates the simple feature version of the edit polygons

```
sfp <- coords$dtf %>%
      st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
      summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
      st_cast("POLYGON") %>% st_transform(crs=6557) %>% st_as_sf()
```

`coords$dtf` is actually from the previous observer for newly drawn polygons.  Changing that object to `dtf`, which is the object for edited polygons solved the issue.  If it is helpful to anyone else, here is the full reproducible solution:

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)
library(leafpm)
library(terra)
library(shinydashboard)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(56)

BAA<-rast(xmin= -124.0, xmax=-121.0, ymin=44.0, ymax=46.0, nrows=500, ncols=500, crs="epsg:4326")
values(BAA)<-rnorm(250000, 150, 40)

rastpath<-tempdir()

if(!dir.exists(rastpath)){
  dir.create(tempdir)
}

writeRaster(BAA, paste(normalizePath(rastpath,"/"), "Basal Area per Acre.tif", sep="/"), overwrite=TRUE)

SPP<-BAA
species<-c("THPL", "ALRU2", "ACMA3", 
           "PSME", "TSHE", "PISI", "ABPR")

values(SPP)<-sample(species, 250000, replace=TRUE)
writeRaster(SPP, paste(normalizePath(rastpath,"/"), "Species Composition.tif", sep="/"), overwrite=TRUE)

ui<-dashboardPage(
  title = "EFI Interactive Mapper",# Start Dashboard Page
  header = dashboardHeader(
    tags$li(class = "dropdown",
            tags$style(".main-header {max-height: 100px}"),
            tags$style(".main-header .logo {height: 100px} .primary-title height {100px}"),
            tags$style(".sidebar-toggle {height: 20px; padding-top: 150px !important;}"),
            tags$style(".navbar {min-height:20px !important}")
    ),
    titleWidth='100%',
    title = span(
      tags$img(src="Rlogo.png", width = '5%', align='right'), 
      column(12, class="title-box", 
             tags$h1(class="primary-title", style='margin-top:5px;', 'EFI Interactive Mapper')
      ))),#End Header
  dashboardSidebar(tags$style(".left-side, .main-sidebar {padding-top: 150px} "),selectInput(inputId = "BIO", "Select a Biometric", 
                                                                                             choices = c("Basal Area per Acre", "Species Composition", "All Biometrics"),
                                                                                             selected = "Basal Area Per Acre"), tags$style(".skin-blue .sidebar a { color: #444; }"),
                   downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download Polygon')
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      tabBox(
        tabPanel('Map', div(style='height:63.0vh', leafletOutput(outputId = "MAP", height="100%"))),
        tabPanel('Table', div(style='overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: auto; max-height:63.0vh', uiOutput("TABLE"))),
        width=12, selected='Table'
      )
    )
  )
)

server<-function(input, output, session){
  
  Bios<-c( "Species Composition", "Basal Area per Acre")
  
  
  tifnames<-c('Species Composition.tif', "Basal Area Per Acre.tif")
  

  rastdf<-data.frame(Bio=Bios[order(Bios)],  paths=paste(normalizePath(rastpath, "/"), tifnames, sep="/"))
  tmp<-lapply(rastdf$paths, rast)
  bio_ras<-c(tmp)
  names(bio_ras)<-rastdf$Bio
  

  
  output$MAP<-renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng=-123.5, lat=45.5, zoom = 10) %>% 
  
      addWMSTiles(
        "https://gis.odf.oregon.gov/ags3/rest/services/Basemaps/ProtectionMap/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}",
        layers = "0",
        options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE),
        attribution = "") %>% 
      
      addPmToolbar(
        toolbarOptions = pmToolbarOptions(drawPolygon = T,
                                          drawCircle = F,
                                          drawPolyline = F,
                                          drawRectangle = F,
                                          editMode = T,
                                          cutPolygon = T,
                                          removalMode = F,
                                          position="topleft"))
  })
  
  proxy <- leafletProxy("MAP", session)
  
  poly<-reactiveValues()
  coords<-reactiveValues()

  
  bio_extract<-reactive({
    if(!is.null(poly$out)){
      
      if(input$BIO=="All Biometrics"){
        bio_use<-bio_ras
      } else{ 
        bio_use<-bio_ras[names(bio_ras)==input$BIO][[1]]
      }  

      fnx<-function(x){
        themean<-mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
        thesd<-sqrt(var(x, na.rm=TRUE))
        out<-list(mean=round(themean,2), sd=round(thesd,2))
        return(out)
      }
      shapevect<-poly$out
      if(input$BIO=="Species Composition"){
        fqt<-freq(bio_use, zones=vect(shapevect)) %>% mutate(pct_comp = 100*count/sum(count))
        
        all_spp<-as.data.frame(expand.grid(levels(bio_use)[[1]][,2], unique(fqt$zone)))
        colnames(all_spp)[1:2]<-c("Species", "ID")
        use_cols<-c("value", "zone", "pct_comp")
        all_spp<-merge(all_spp, fqt[,use_cols], by.x=c("Species", "ID"), by.y=c("value", "zone"), all.x=TRUE, all.y=FALSE)
        all_spp$pct_comp[is.na(all_spp$pct_comp)]<-0
        spp_out<-tidyr::pivot_wider(all_spp, id_cols=ID, names_from = Species, values_from = pct_comp) %>% as.data.frame()
        e<-cbind(shapevect, as.data.frame(spp_out))
        #cbind(shapevect, spp_out)
        
      }else{
        if(input$BIO=="All Biometrics"){
          ext_ras<-bio_use[names(bio_use)!= "Species Composition"]
          
          e <- lapply(ext_ras, extract, shapevect, fnx, bind = FALSE, raw=FALSE)
          
          spp_ras<-bio_use[names(bio_use)== "Species Composition"][[1]]
          fqt<-freq(spp_ras, zones=vect(shapevect)) %>% mutate(pct_comp = 100*count/sum(count))
          
          all_spp<-as.data.frame(expand.grid(levels(spp_ras)[[1]][,2], unique(fqt$zone)))
          colnames(all_spp)[1:2]<-c("Species", "ID")
          use_cols<-c("value", "zone", "pct_comp")
          all_spp<-merge(all_spp, fqt[,use_cols], by.x=c("Species", "ID"), by.y=c("value", "zone"), all.x=TRUE, all.y=FALSE)
          all_spp$pct_comp[is.na(all_spp$pct_comp)]<-0
          spp_out<-tidyr::pivot_wider(all_spp, id_cols=ID, names_from = Species, values_from = pct_comp) %>% as.data.frame()
          e[[length(e)+1]]<-spp_out
          names(e)[length(e)]<-"Species Composition"
          e<-lapply(e, function(X, Y){cbind(Y, as.data.frame(X))}, shapevect) 
        }else{
          e <- terra::extract(bio_use, shapevect, fnx, bind = FALSE)
          
          e<-cbind(shapevect, as.data.frame(e))
          #   st_as_sf(cbind(shapevect, e[, -1, drop = FALSE]))
        }
      } 
      
      return(e)
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$MAP_draw_new_feature, {
    req(input$BIO)
    coords$dtf<-data.frame(do.call( rbind, do.call(cbind,input$MAP_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates)))
    colnames(coords$dtf)<-c("long", "lat")
    sfp <- coords$dtf %>%
      st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
      summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
      st_cast("POLYGON") %>% st_transform(crs=6557) %>% st_as_sf()
    
    row.names(sfp)<-input$MAP_draw_new_feature$properties$layerId
    if(is.null(poly$out)){
      poly$out<-sfp
      isolate(print(row.names(poly$out)))
    }else{
      rn<-row.names(poly$out)
      poly$out<-rbind(poly$out, sfp)
      row.names(poly$out)[-nrow(poly$out)]<-rn
      row.names(poly$out)[nrow(poly$out)]<-row.names(sfp)
      isolate(print(row.names(poly$out)))
    }
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$MAP_draw_edited_features, {
    
    dtf<-data.frame(do.call(rbind, do.call(cbind, input$MAP_draw_edited_features$geometry$coordinates)))
    colnames(dtf)<-c("long", "lat")
    
    sfp <- dtf %>%
      st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
      summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
      st_cast("POLYGON") %>% st_transform(crs=6557) %>% st_as_sf()
    
    row.names(sfp)<-input$MAP_draw_edited_features$properties$layerId
    rn<-row.names(poly$out)
    isolate(poly$out)
    poly$out<-poly$out[!row.names(poly$out) %in% row.names(sfp),]
    
    row.names(poly$out)<-rn[!rn %in% rownames(sfp)]
    isolate(poly$out)
    poly$out<-rbind(poly$out, sfp)
    row.names(poly$out)[1:(nrow(poly$out)-1)]<-rn[!rn %in% rownames(sfp)]
    row.names(poly$out)[nrow(poly$out)]<-row.names(sfp)
    
    isolate(poly$out)
    
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$drawnPoly_deleted_features, { 
    
    f <- input$drawnPoly_deleted_features
    ids<-lapply(f$features, function(x){unlist(x$properties$layerId)})
    polys$out<-polys$out[!row.names(polys$out) %in% ids ,]
    
  }) 
  
  output$TABLE<-renderUI({
    req(input$BIO)
    if(!is.null(poly$out)){
      data.out<-bio_extract() 
      
      if(input$BIO=="All Biometrics"){
        
        for(i in 1:length(data.out)){
          if(i < length(data.out)){
            data.out[[i]]<-as.data.frame(data.out[[i]] %>% st_drop_geometry())
            
            colnames(data.out[[i]])<-c("Area of Interest","Estimate Mean", "Estimate Standard Deviation",
                                       "Lower Bound <br> 95% Prediction Interval <br> Mean", "Lower Bound <br> 95% Prediction Interval <br> Standard Deviation",
                                       "Upper Bound <br> 95% Prediction Interval <br> Mean", "Upper Bound <br> 95% Prediction Interval <br> Standard Deviation")
          }else{
            data.out[[i]]<-data.out[[i]] %>% st_drop_geometry() %>% mutate(across(.cols=everything(), ~paste(round(.x, 1), "%"))) %>% as.data.frame()
            
            colnames(data.out[[i]])[1]<-"Area of Interest"
          }
          
        }
        
        kbl_out<-lapply(data.out, function(X){
          kbl(X, format="html", align="c", escape=FALSE, col.names=colnames(X)) %>% 
            column_spec(column=c(1:ncol(X)), width_min="3.5cm") %>% 
            kable_styling()
        })
        
        table_formatter<-function(tname, tkbl){
          paste0("<center><b><u><font size = '+2'>", tname, "</font></u></b></center>",
                 "<br><center>", tkbl, "</center><br>")}
        
        HTML(table_formatter(names(data.out), kbl_out))
        
      }else{
        data.out<-data.out %>% st_drop_geometry()
        table_formatter<-function(tname, tkbl){
          paste0("<center><b><u><font size = '+2'>", tname, "</font></u></b></center>",
                 "<br><center>", tkbl, "</center><br>")}
        
        if(input$BIO!="Species Composition"){
          use_names<-c("Area of Interest","Estimate Mean", "Estimate Standard Deviation",
                       "Lower Bound <br> 95% Prediction Interval <br> Mean", "Lower Bound <br> 95% Prediction Interval <br> Standard Deviation",
                       "Upper Bound <br> 95% Prediction Interval <br> Mean", "Upper Bound <br> 95% Prediction Interval <br> Standard Deviation")
        }else{
          
          use_names<-colnames(data.out)
          data.out<-data.out %>% mutate(across(.cols=everything(), ~paste(round(.x, 1), "%")))
        }
        kbl_out<-kbl(data.out, format="html", escape = FALSE, col.names=use_names, align="c") %>% 
          column_spec(column=c(1:ncol(data.out)), width_min = "3.5cm") %>% 
          kable_styling()
        HTML(table_formatter(input$BIO, kbl_out))
      }
    }  
  })
  
  output$downloadData<-downloadHandler(
    
    filename <- function(){
      fname<-input$BIO
      paste(fname, "Polygon.gpkg", sep="_")}, 
    
    content = function(file) {
      #   req(polys$out)
      if (length(Sys.glob(paste(input$BIO, "*", sep=".")))>0){
        file.remove(Sys.glob(paste(input$BIO, "*", sep=".")))
      }
      
      owd<-setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      polys_out<-bio.extract()
      if(input$BIO=="All Biometrics"){
        polys_out2<-rapply(polys_out, function(X){merge(X, X, by=names(X)[1])}, how="replace")
      }else{
        polys_out2<-polys_out
      }
      st_write(polys_out2, "polyExport.gpkg", "GPKG", append=FALSE)  
      file.rename("polyExport.gpkg", file)  
      
      if (length(Sys.glob("polyExport.*"))>0){
        file.remove(Sys.glob("polyExport.*"))
      }
    })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```